# Akka HTTP: How to have the flow Http().superPool() not throw exceptions when encountering a bad URL?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have lots of URLs which I'd like to get using Akka HTTP, and using streams.

The URLs might be mal-formed or the DNS might not be able to resolve the host name. In those cases, I'd like the superPool() flow to simply return a Failure as the Try[HTTPResponse] instead of throwing an exception and terminating the whole stream.

How should I go about doing this? I've searched for it but have come up with nothing, can't find a way to handle esceptions in the docs themselves.

EDIT: After fiddling a bit more, I've found that the only issue is with HTTPS urls, and even then the stream isn't closed, but I'm getting error printed on the console which shouldn't happen. Here is a small example to reproduce:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}    
import akka.NotUsed
import scala.util.Success
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
Source.single((HttpRequest(uri = "https://a.com"), NotUsed))
          .via(Http().superPool[NotUsed]())
          .map(_ match {
              case (Success(v), _) => {v.discardEntityBytes(); println("Success")}
              case _ => println("Failure")
          })
          .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Could it be that the `Http().superPool` expects HTTP urls and there's some other way to work with HTTPS?

EDIT 2: I've opened an issue with the project: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/3138

Comment: Is it important that the `Failure` is sent downstream, or is it only important that the stream isn't closed?

Comment: @Mateusz It's more important that the stream isn't closed, though it would definitely be nicer to get a Failure sent downstream

Comment: I would recommend logging this as an issue in the project issue tracker so a maintainer can triage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with akka-http 10.1.11 and has been fixed in 10.1.12.
In the latter version, no errors are logged by default with both HTTP and HTTPS urls.

Answer (score 1):

Since `superPool` should already return `Try` I would consider it error and report issue. At least I haven't found documentation saying that invalid requrest should terminate the stream instead or returning `Failure`.

As a workaround I would try to use supervision strategy:

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: Malformed URL Exception => Supervision.Resume // put your exception type here
  case _                          => Supervision.Stop
}

Http().superPool()
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
```

Comment: The exception was still being thrown despite doing the things you mentioned. So I fiddled around with the URL a bit, and noticed that for an unknown host name with `http://`, the `Failure` would be sent downstream, but with `https://` it would send the `Failure` downstream but errors are also printed

Comment: Also, unlike my previous assumptions, it seems the stream isn't getting closed, since the sink continues to receive `Success`s even after the failure. The point then, I suppose, is why are the errors getting printed.

Comment: From what I understand error is logged by `superPool` `Flow` before anything could handle it. You can pass `loggerAdapter` as superPool argument to configure it to be something that ignores such errors if you want to.